# Issue with arrays and methods

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

So what I'm trying to do with this program is take two arrays, and then merge them into a third array. The main method takes the data from a specified file and then creates arrays for each line, and there are only two lines. The files is formatted like this:

```
11 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 6 7 8 9 10 11
8 -33 -22 -11 44 55 66 77 88
```

After the arrays are created, I try to call the merge method I've created but I get this error from Netbeans:

'.class' expected

unexpected type

required: value

found: class

and I don't really know what that means, and Netbeans tries fixing it by creating other classes.
All of my code is below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayMerge
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   File inputDataFile = new File(args[0]);
   try
   {
       Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inputDataFile);   
       Scanner keyboardin = new Scanner(System.in);
       int aSize = inputFile.nextInt();
       int a[] = new int[aSize];
       for (int i= 0 ; i<aSize; i++ )
           {
               a[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
           }
       int bSize = inputFile.nextInt();
       int b[] = new int[bSize];
       for (int j = 0; j < bSize; j++)
           {
               b[j] = inputFile.nextInt();
           }
       int c[] = ArrayMerge.merge(a, b);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));




   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e)
   {
       System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
   }



}

public static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) 
{
            // merge 2 sorted arrays

            int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
            int i=0, j=0, k=0;

            while (i<a.length && j<b.length) {
                    c[k++] = (a[i]<b[j]? a[i++]: b[j++]);
            } // end while

            while (j<b.length) {
                    c[k++] = b[j++];
            } // end while

            while (i<a.length) {
                    c[k++] = a[i++];
            } // end while

            return c;
    } // end merge()
```

}

Update: I solved my own issue. I forgot that arrays aren't called by their name and brackets, but merely the variable name. After realizing this, I figured out that I had to move the line that had the error into the Try{} block. I've updated the code above to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `merge()` method is declared *outside* the class.

Move the closing curly bracket of the class from *above* the `merge()` method to *below* it.

Comment: Check the parentheses again. merge() is in the same class. I messed up the whitespace in the copy/pasting to StackOverflow so they don't line up when you look at them, but if you count them it does.